# Where to store 4 arrays, 10 elements each

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-5, global-variables

I have some pages that show 4 different menu sidebars depending on the page, and I want to decide where to store these menu items: store them in global arrays or in database. I have 4 methods that use these menu items, and I don't want to repeat writing these menu items in each method.

I guess storing them in database needs the script to connect to the database in every page load. So I thought to store them in 4 global arrays, that contain 10 elements each.

- Is 4 arrays of 10 elements too big (memory usage?) to be defined as global variables?
- Is it a good choice to store them in global arrays rather than in database table? (performance?)
- Is there a better solution?

Comment: At some point, you'll want to edit it through the admin panel and/or add some data to these arrays. So keeping this kind of data in a DB table sounds like a good idea.

Comment: If you don't need to edit them very often you could just stick them into a config file and read them from there.

Comment: Any diffrence on memory usage storing them in a config file compared to storing them in controller's constructor?